# undefined is not an object(evaluating '_route$params.userName') in react-native

Tags: parameters, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation-v5

When I am trying to pass data from Login Screen to MyProfile Screen in react native then I face this issue.

I am confusing what I miss in this code so someone can please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you in advanced.

[image]

Login Screen

```
const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


    function resetTextInput() {

        navigation.navigate('MyProfileScreen', { userName: name, userPwd: password });
        console.log("reset TextInput");
        setName("");
        setPassword("");
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.txtTitle}>Login</Text>
            <View style={{ marginTop: 80 }}>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder={'Username'}
                    style={styles.txtInput}
                    onChangeText={(name) => { setName(name) }}
                    value={name}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder={'Password'}
                    style={styles.txtInput}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(password) => { setPassword(password) }}
                    value={password}
                />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={() => { resetTextInput() }}>
                <Text style={styles.loginBtnTxt}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

MyProfile Screen

```
const MyProfile = ({ route}) => {
 
     const { userName, userPwd } = route.params;

    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

            <Image source={require('./../../../asstes/images/profileimg.png')} style={styles.imgProfile} />

            <Text style={styles.userData}>Username:- {JSON.stringify(userName)}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.userData}>Password:-{JSON.stringify(userPwd)} </Text>

        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your stack? show us where you are using the MyProfile screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not navigating but you have probably tried to click the screen.

The easiest way to fix this issue is to handle nulls.

```
const MyProfile = ({ route}) => {
 
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

            <Image source={require('./../../../asstes/images/profileimg.png')} style={styles.imgProfile} />

            <Text style={styles.userData}>Username:- {JSON.stringify(route?.params?.userName)}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.userData}>Password:-{JSON.stringify(route?.params?.userPwd)} </Text>

        </View>
    )
}
```

This will make sure that you dont get crashes because of nulls.

Suggestion:
Think of using something like the React context to manage logins and also look into auth flow
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow